# Using SWIG with C++ template functions

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I have a few template functions for map in c++ and I want to use them in ruby.

```
template <class Collection>
const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& FindWithDefault(
    const Collection& collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
    const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& value) {
  typename Collection::const_iterator it = collection.find(key);
  if (it == collection.end()) {
    return value;
  }
  return it->second;
}
```

In c++ it works like this

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Map;
    Map m;
    std::string d= FindWithDefault(m, "foo", "");
    std::cout << d << "\n";
    //    
    m["foo"] = "bar";
    d=  FindWithDefault(m, "foo", "");
    std::cout << d << "\n";
    // bar
}
```

Its easy to make use of map and set in ruby by looking at the answer of the question I have answered before(take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052799/using-c-stl-set-with-swig)).

As for this question My interface file has this

```
%include <std_map.i>
namespace std {
   %template(IntMap) map<int,int>;
}
template <typename Collection>
const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& FindWithDefault(
    const Collection& collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
    const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& value) ;
%template(d) FindWithDefault<std::map<int,int> >;
```

My c++ header file has the complete function mentioned above. Now when I try to check this in Irb, the map works fine, but I get an error on using the template function

```
2.2.1 :001 > a = Example::IntMap.new
 => std::map<int,int,std::less< int >,std::allocator< std::pair< int const,int > > > {} 
2.2.1 :002 > a[1]=2
 => 2 
2.2.1 :003 > a[5]=3
 => 3 
2.2.1 :004 > a[4]=11
 => 11 
2.2.1 :005 > a
 => std::map<int,int,std::less< int >,std::allocator< std::pair< int const,int > > > {1=>2,4=>11,5=>3} 
2.2.1 :006 > b=Example::d(a,2,2)
ArgumentError: Wrong arguments for overloaded method 'd'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    std::map< int,int,std::less< int >,std::allocator< std::pair< int const,int > > >::value_type::second_type const & d(int a, int b)
    std::map< int,int,std::less< int >,std::allocator< std::pair< int const,int > > >::value_type::second_type const & d(std::map< int,int,std::less< int >,std::allocator< std::pair< int const,int > > > const &collection, std::map< int,int,std::less< int >,std::allocator< std::pair< int const,int > > >::value_type::first_type const &key, std::map< int,int,std::less< int >,std::allocator< std::pair< int const,int > > >::value_type::second_type const &value)

    from (irb):6:in `d'
    from (irb):6
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

How can I make this work ?

Comment: (In response to a previous comment: The question title is the primary mechanism to communicate content to users. The use of your posts *to other members of the community* is the prime value for Stack Overflow, and thus a title that is vague and unlikely to be searched for by someone with the same problem is a very good reason for a downvote: It means that the post has low value to the community. It's nothing personal, just a method for prioritizing.)

Comment: I am sorry for lashing out. Stackoverflow is a wonderful place that I have using for quite some time now. But I am really surprised that naive questions that could be solved by a single google search are top voted and many legit and complex questions are left unanswered.  Take a look at this question that I had asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603146/how-to-efficiently-find-k-nearest-neighbours-from-a-kd-tree,  this one was completely left out by the community despite being very useful. I later found out myself by reading a paper and this lead to massive speedup of around 1100 times.

Comment: Well, the more complex a question is, the more niche its interest usually is, no matter its intellectually value or difficulty. But such questions are surely never downvoted; they may simply not be interesting to most people. But it's still great to have those, and they may well build up upvotes over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems SWIG has trouble determining the type of `Collection::value_type::first_type` and `Collection::value_type::second_type`. I am not exactly sure why.

A possible solution / workaround that happens to work in this case is to replace `Collection::value_type::first_type` with `Collection::key_type` and `Collection::value_type::second_type` with `Collection::mapped_type`. It is sufficient to do this in the SWIG interface file, i.e., leave your C++ code unchanged but put this in the interface file instead:

```
%include <std_map.i>
namespace std {
   %template(IntMap) map<int,int>;
}
template <typename Collection>
const typename Collection::mapped_type& FindWithDefault(
    const Collection& collection,
    const typename Collection::key_type& key,
    const typename Collection::mapped_type& value) ;
%template(d) FindWithDefault<std::map<int,int> >;
```

Comment: This is it. The reason it struggles with `value_type::first_type`/`value_type::second_type` is simply because std_map.i doesn't seem to define it anywhere, at least not for ruby.

Comment: But Lib/std/std_map.i does typedef `std::map<_Key, _Tp>::value_type` to be `std::pair< const _Key, _Tp >` [here](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/std/std_map.i#L76), and this is used/%included by the language specific std_map.i file for ruby (and python). I am still puzzled why the code in the question doesn't just work.

Comment: @m7thon Thanks a lot for the answer. This really saved me from a lot of trouble. I just have a few questions now.                                                                       Did you figure this out using [std_map.i](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/std/std_map.i#L76)  or by reading documentation ?   Also How do I handle  std::map<_Key, _Tp>::value_type I am getting some weird errors with std::pair<int,int> ?  Thanks again this answer was really useful

Comment: The error (which is generated by SWIG) tells that a `key` argument of type `std::map<int,int,... >::value_type::first_type const &` is expected. Clearly, this type is just an `int &` and you provide an `int` (well, something SWIG should be able to convert). So, SWIG didn't understand this type. I am still not sure why. I tried the simpler `Container::key_type`, which works. SWIG does has an excellent (albeit long) documentation, which I have consulted many times. Understanding SWIG basics is essential. Peeking at the SWIG library files and the generated wrapper code is also very insightful.